# Selenium: how to move physical mouse pointer outside browser window

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid2

I am using selenium with Grid to test web application. But I get unexpected results when the physical mouse is over the browser window.

Issue details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3802

I would like to move the physical mouse outside of browser window. I am not sure how to achieve it. I am using selenium grid to run tests on remote machines, so I would require something that would work over grid.

Comment: You can't do it with just Selenium. [Selenium Grid Extras](https://github.com/groupon/Selenium-Grid-Extras) has the ability to move the mouse on remote machines.

Comment: But you might be able to fix the root cause. What unexpected results are you seeing when the mouse is over the browser window? What browser? IE11?

Comment: Root cause may not be fixable as this issue is due to browser drivers and  appear time and again. I am getting this on [Chrome](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3802) at the moment, but this has been reported on IE and Firefox as well (at some point).

Comment: I am using Grid to run the test, so I need a solution that would work over a grid.

Comment: Maybe that's why the Selenium Grid Extras has that ability - to get around that issue. I haven't tried it myself. I suggest you check out the project and give it a shot.